# Visual Studio 2017 cast to SqlDatabaseTestClass error when opening SQL unit test cs file

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, unit-testing

In Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.3) when opening a SQL unit test file I get the following error and the test designer refuses to display:

```
[A]Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.SqlDatabaseTestClass cannot be cast to [B]Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.SqlDatabaseTestClass.

Type A originates from 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting, 
Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' in the context 'LoadNeither' 
at location 'C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_892b908b\ProjectAssemblies\hxuywdf401\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.dll'. 

Type B originates from 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting, 
Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' in the context 'LoadFrom' 
at location 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\SQLDB\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.dll'.
```

Call stack:

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.UnitTesting.Design.Serialization.SqlUnitTestClassSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

The SQL unit test files used to open and other members of my team do not have this problem (so the problem must be local to my machine rather than being a problem with the project itself).